# Can SSIS put command to compute on Vertica(ELT)

Tags: ssis, vertica

I have some questions about SSIS and Vertica.

1. Can SSIS send or put command to compute or transform data on Vertica target server(ELT not ETL) ?
2. Can SSIS connect to Unix/Linux for call a Shell Script?

Thanks and Best Regards,

Comment: for first one Im not sure, but for second one, you can take a look for Execute Process task, inside that you can configure your own exe, we use this to call SFTP before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What research have you done on this? Did you check the vendor's website for SSIS connection managers ([click here](https://www.vertica.com/kb/SSIScg/Content/Partner/SSIScg.htm))?
2. It might be possible. You can execute PowerShell scripts, call applications, etc. via the Execute Process task.

Comment: I am wondering why always i found good answers without any upvote in ssis tag +1